For how much time filebeat retains data if any connectivity issues with elasticsearch occur?
The problem statement is
"For how much time filebeat will store data at its own repository if its connection with its output is disrupted due to any reason? Output can be elasticsearch or kafka"

Tldr;
By default Filebeat will queue 3200 events.
Then will stop reading new lines.
More info
Filebeat support 2 types of queue:

in memory (default)
persistent

Both will have specific configuration regarding the amount of events they can store.
They will be deleting from the queue the event that have been consumed/dropped by the output (which ever type you use, Kafka/Elasticsearch ...)
In case the queue is reaching it maximum size. Filebeat will depending on the input either stop consuming or actively refuse incoming event.
Source
